# MySQL функция в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть MySQL функция:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(INTERVAL - 1 day + CURRENT_DATE())
```

Как это будет в виде php?

Как я понял, не так:

```
<?php
$time_today = strtotime('today midnight');
$time_yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');

$other_time = $time_yesterday + time();
?>
```

и не так:

```
<?php
$time_today = strtotime('today midnight');
$time_yesterday = strtotime('-1 day');

$other_time = $time_yesterday + $time_today;
?>
```

Comment: strtotime('-1 day')

Comment: @Etki, почему ещё прибавляется текущая дата то?

>> + CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: @ModaL, потому что в SQL используется такая сущеость, как интервал. На PHP с интервалами работают обычно через классы:

    $today = new DateTime('today');
    $today->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $timestamp = $now->getTimestamp();

Comment: @Etki, можно мне пример без класса этого, пожалуйста? Мне нужно знать, как всё работает стандартными функциями PHP.

Comment: @Etki, прекрасно, спасибо тебе. Преврати свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal), PHP уже давно является ОО языком. Это и есть стандартный функционал. Подход в рамках функциональной парадигмы я показал выше, если вам нужен абсолютно идентичный код -

```
$timestampDayAgo = -24 * 60 * 60 + strtotime('today');
```

(и то на самом деле мускул оперирует датами, переводя их в timestamp в самом конце).